# RDLC report not working on server but working on local machine

Tags: .net, rdlc

`RDLC` report working fine on local system but when running on the server getting error

> The element 'buildProviders' cannot be defined below the application
>   level.

I added the Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime but still getting the same error. I am using `.Net` framework 4

Comment: Can you add some details to explain better where you have the problem?

Comment: RDLC report is working fine when running on local machine but when i am trying to run on server  i am getting the error as i mentioned above. i have added Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime to the solution as i have added all necessary dlls but still getting the error.

Comment: did you checked this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586995/the-element-buildproviders-cannot-be-defined-below-the-application-level